# unlist list of dictionaries in dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, dataframe

My current DataFrame is something looks like this:

```
Index  Animal                                                   AnimalClassId
0      [{animalid:1,color:red,name:cat},{animalid:2,color:blue,name:cat2}]  1
1      [{animalid:3,color:pink,name:pig}]                                   2
```

so first column animal is a list of of dictionary for each row. Each Animal row has list with different length.

My ideal output is:

```
Index  Animal                           AnimalClassId
0      {animalid:1,color:red,name:cat}       1
1      {animalid:2,color:blue,name:cat2}     1
2      {animalid:3,color:pink,name:pig}      2
```

Also this dataset is enormously large (100000+ rows) so I'm trying to avoid loop through every row. Any good methods for quick implementation? I would appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: Why don't you un-nest your dictionary into columns? Surely this is the reason you are facing performance issues: Pandas series aren't designed to hold dictionaries. I advise you change your "ideal output" to something *more* ideal.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with:

```
ideal_df = df.set_index(["AnimalClassId"])["Animal"]\
  .apply(pd.Series)\
  .stack()\
  .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)\
  .reset_index()

ideal_df.columns = ["AnimalClassId", "Animal"]
```

(Note you can put this all one one line or break it up into separate lines)

Sample:

input (your example):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Animal": [
        [{"animalid":1,"color":"red","name":"cat"}, {"animalid":2,"color":"blue","name":"cat2"}],
        [{"animalid":3,"color":"pink","name":"pig"}]
    ], 
    "AnimalClassId": [1, 2]
})

print(df)
                                              Animal  AnimalClassId
0  [{'animalid': 1, 'color': 'red', 'name': 'cat'...              1
1  [{'animalid': 3, 'color': 'pink', 'name': 'pig'}]              2
```

output:

```
print(ideal_df)

   AnimalClassId                                            Animal
0              1    {'animalid': 1, 'color': 'red', 'name': 'cat'}
1              1  {'animalid': 2, 'color': 'blue', 'name': 'cat2'}
2              2   {'animalid': 3, 'color': 'pink', 'name': 'pig'}
```

If you have more columns than just "AnimalClassId", you'll need to include those in the list passed to `set_index`, and increase the `level` param passed to `reset_index` by 1 for each additional column. For example, if you had the column "AnimalHabitat", then you would need `set_index(["AnimalClassId", "AnimalHabitat"])` and `reset_index(level=2, drop=True)`.

This is still going to have to loop over your data behind the scenes. Since the data in the "Animal" column is not uniform (lists of varying length) I doubt there is a way to expand each element in a vectorized way, but this will do the trick.

Comment: for some reason, the code you provided doesn't work. I think the part "pd.Series" is supposed to expand every item in the list? For mine, my df still stay the same. Any clues on that?

Comment: @YixianWang try applying each method sequentially rather than all at once and see if something seems off. At the very least something should happen, I don't think it's possible for your df to stay the same with all these methods applied.

Comment: @YixianWang did you use `df` or `ideal_df`?

Answer (score 0):

You must reconstruct it .It's important to carefully build each column.
 A simple way to do that:

```
def refactor(df):
    animals=[]
    for list in df.Animal : animals.extend(list) # for O(n) operation
    animalclassids=[ id for nb,id in zip(df.Animal.apply(len),df.AnimalClassId)\ 
                     for k in range(nb)]   
    df2= pd.DataFrame({'Animal':animals, 'AnimalClassId':animalclassids})
    return df2
```

the loop for col 1 avoid `df.Animal.sum()` which seems O(n²).

```
>>> refactor(df)
                                             Animal  AnimalClassId
0    {'animalid': 1, 'color': 'red', 'name': 'cat'}              1
1  {'animalid': 2, 'color': 'blue', 'name': 'cat2'}              1
2   {'animalid': 3, 'color': 'pink', 'name': 'pig'}              2

>>> df2=pd.concat((df,)*50000)

>>> len(df2)
100000

>>> %time res=refactor(df2)
Wall time: 550 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

## Don't use a series of dictionaries

Pandas stands for "panel data" and works best when each series represents a different field. So you can expand your dataframe, then un-nest your dictionaries:

```
# expand dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'Animal': np.concatenate(df['Animal']),
                   'AnimalClassId': np.repeat(df['AnimalClassId'],
                                              df['Animal'].str.len())})

# un-nested dictionaries into series
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.pop('Animal').values.tolist()))

print(df)

   AnimalClassId  animalid color  name
0              1         1   red   cat
0              1         1   red   cat
1              2         2  blue  cat2
```

This method has the advantage that the resultant dataframes `index` retains the index from the *original* dataframe for each row.